# Wordpress previous / Next Button execute child category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, execute

I have this problem:

Parente category (8)
- Child category (12)

I like to execute the post of the child category from the previous / Next preview.

the child contains 2 post (the first two) - maybe it`s easier to execute "the first two"

Any ideas?

Comment: where is your php code ?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please clarify and add the wanted output and the available input.

Comment: Input PHP Code:

    <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link(__('%link &raquo;', 'blogtxt')) ?></div>
<div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link(__('&laquo; %link', 'blogtxt')) ?></div>


Output: execute the child category (ID 12) / Only show posts of parent category (Id 8)

Answer (score 0):

Input PHP Code:

```
<div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link(__('%link &raquo;', 'blogtxt')) ?></div>
```

Output: execute the child category (ID 12) / Only show posts of parent category (Id 8)